# Webcam software with live chroma keying/green screen

Tags: video, webcam, video-editor, effects

I want to take live camera feed (from webcam or other source) and apply a chroma key effect in order to remove the background (i.e. green screening) and then want to replace the background with a different image or video. See examples below:

Original footage

[image]

Edited footage

[image]

I then want to save this output to an image or record a video from it. Is any software available to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some help I found that the easiest way to accomplish this is by using [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/):

> Free and open source software for video recording and live streaming.
>   Download and start streaming quickly and easily on Windows, Mac or
>   Linux.

After installing and launching the software click on the + button under Sources to add your webcam as an input source.

[image]

Give your input a name in case you'll be using multiple camera inputs. Choose your webcam (if you have more than one) and then press OK. Back in the main window right click on the webcam source and select Filters

[image]

Press on the + button under Effect Filters and select Chroma Key and give it a new name.

[image]

From here you can select the colour that you wish to remove. You can choose from the presets or choose your own colour.

[image]

To see the full effect you'll need to have something in the background. In the main window select a new source. You can choose an image, video or additional camera.

[image]

Now you'll see the media source appear behind your webcam!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a web app](https://flect-lab-web.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/001_virtual_background/index.html) which can add a virtual background using image, video, your browser, or screen. It can also put your face in the corner so you can walk through something else on your screen.

It's referenced in this article about [how to do Mmhmm style presentations in Linux](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-easiest-way-in-the-world-to-make-mmhmm-like-presentations-in-video-conferencing-f48e594482ed).

If using it in a live call, you could screen-share that browser tab.